# How to access gmail account via javamail

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I try to access email account on a certain email server via "imap" through java mail. I did some research on this. And I find the following code which works for gmail.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class DeleteMessageExample {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
    String host = args[0];
    String username = args[1];
    String password = args[2];

    // Get session
    Session session = Session.getInstance(
      System.getProperties(), null);

    // Get the store
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(host, username, password);

    // Get folder
    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (
      new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // Get directory
    Message message[] = folder.getMessages();
    for (int i=0, n=message.length; i<n; i++) {
       System.out.println(i + ": " + message[i].getFrom()[0] 
         + "\t" + message[i].getSubject());

       System.out.println("Do you want to delete message? [YES to delete]");
       String line = reader.readLine();
       // Mark as deleted if appropriate
       if ("YES".equals(line)) {
         message[i].setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
       }
    }

    // Close connection 
    folder.close(true);
    store.close();
        }
    }
```

However, I need to specify the args[0] to be imap.gmail.com  args[1] to be usrname, args[2] to be password. And if I replace imap.gmail.com by the ip address  74.125.224.86, it no longer work.

My question is suppose I have an account on yahoo mail, what the hostname I should use?
I tried imap.yahoo.com, mail.yahoo.com and the ip address.

If you know the answer, would you mind also told me what is the regular rule to find out what kind hostname I should use?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you tried to connect with Thunderbird to yahoo/IMAP?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Gmail, Yahoo Mail's IMAP services is not a totally standard IMAP service. You need send some special tokens before you login. You need to modify the JavaMail API in order to connect to Yahoo Mail through IMAP. The latest JavaMail 1.4.4-SNAPSHOT release supports Yahoo Mail as well. You can get it [here](http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/pages/Yahoo)